# How to handle nil parameter, when data inserted in create method

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

- Elixir: 1.6
- Phoenix: 1.3

I tried to insert parameter, but when one of parameters like 'memo' is null.
How can I handle nil parameter in general?
I just wanna nil check like this.

```
memo = (memo == nil ? "" : memo)
```

What is the best practice of nil check in Elixir. 
if or case or anything else?

In this case, when _params memo is nil, it goes error code.

```
def create(conn, _params) do
  price = _params["price"]
  amount = _params["amount"]
  memo = _params["memo"]
  sales = %{price: price,
               amount: amount,
               memo: memo}
case Casher.create_sales(sales) do
  {:ok, sales} ->
  conn
    |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :success))
  {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
    render(conn, "error.html")
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact transaction would be:

```
memo = if memo == nil, do: "", else: memo
```

A more idiomatic way which will only work if memo can't be `false` (`false` will turn into `""` as well) is this:

```
memo = memo || ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives to what has been mentioned:

```
memo = case memo do
  nil -> ""
  _ -> memo
end
```

```
memo = case is_nil(memo) do
  true -> ""
  _ -> memo
end
```